# Questions about math font and \definefallbackfamily in ConTeXt

Tags: math-mode, context

I am working with some basic maths here and the latest version of ConTeXt. However, I think something has changed in ConTeXt, because the following MWE, from Aditya, was working fine previously:

```
\definefontfamily[mainface][rm][Minion Pro]
\definefallbackfamily[mainface][math][Minion Pro][math:lowercaseitalic]
\definefallbackfamily[mainface][math][Minion Pro][math:digitsnormal]
\definefontfamily[mainface][math][TeX Gyre Pagella Math]
\setupbodyfont[mainface]

\starttext
\startformula
c^2 = a^2 + b^2
\stopformula
\stoptext
```

Now, the italic font of Minion Pro is replaced for regular.

**Questions:**

1. How can i set the Minion Pro italic font for maths?
2. How can i use characters like ñ or accents (Producción) with Minion
   Pro in math mode?
3. Is there any way to use only some symbols like +, - from Minion Pro
   in math mode

Thank you guys.

ConTeXt  ver: 2016.08.27 13:35 MKIV beta
luatex version 0.98.1 (tex live 2017/dev)

Comment: Where is TeX Live 2017/dev available from? If you are using development or beta versions of LuaTeX/ConTeXt then (1) you must be happy to accept bugs; (2) you should report the bugs to the appropriate people rather than asking here, because the appropriate people are (a) in the best position to fix them and (b) make development/beta versions available precisely so that users will inform them of bugs.

Comment: @cfr: If I run `luatex --version` for the binary shipped with [ConTeXt standalone](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Standalone), I get `This is LuaTeX, Version 0.98.1 (TeX Live 2017/dev)`

Comment: Since the same question was asked on the mailing list (now with answers), it might be good if you answer the question yourself and mark it as selected. Otherwise, people might spend time on a non-existing problem.

Comment: @mickep Can you provide a link meanwhile?

Comment: @Aditya That explains it. It is cutting-edge and, hence, it is going to have bugs. (I don't say 'may have': anything this complex will have. Of course, that's true for the stable stuff shipped with distributions, too, but they are less likely to be as major. No guarantees, of course, but probabilities.)

Comment: @cfr Sure, see [ntg.nl](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2016/086676.html). Also, to jl4c, in case you think your problem is only partially solved from the answer on that thread, you can update your question accordingly. Finally, it might be nice mentioning the cross posting. Anyways, I hope the problem is now solved!

Comment: Cross-postings should be linked when asking a question to avoid duplication of effort, which understandably annoys people whose efforts they are!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved on the ConTeXt mailing list https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2016/086676.html